# Subset the 1st row of each obvservation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the data frame:

```
Observations Value
obs 1     1
obs 1     2
obs 1     3
obs 1     4
obs 2     5
obs 2     6
obs 2     7
obs 3     8
obs 3     9
```

Is it possible to subset only the first row of each observation?

Such that I get:

```
Observations Value
obs 1     1
obs 2     5
obs 3     8
```

Comment: I'd recommend a matrix for this type of table instead of a data frame, since its all numerical and matrices have better performance

Comment: @hedgedandlevered - It's not all numeric.  The first column is a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use the `duplicated` function for this.

```
> df[!duplicated(df$Observations), ]
#   Observations Value
# 1        obs 1     1
# 5        obs 2     5
# 8        obs 3     8
```

Another alternative would be

```
> unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$Observations), `[`, 1,), levels(df$Observations))
#   Observations Value
# 1        obs 1     1
# 5        obs 2     5
# 8        obs 3     8
```

Although the latter uses a loop, and will be many moons slower than the `duplicated` method.

`do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$Observations), "[", 1,))` could also be used.

Answer (score 2):

Could also use `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(dat, Observations) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#Groups: Observations
#
#  Observations Value
#1        obs_1     1
#2        obs_2     5
#3        obs_3     8
```

Using the sample data by @akrun:

```
set.seed(49)
dat <- data.frame(Observations=sample(LETTERS, 1e5, replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(1e5))
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
f1 <- function(){aggregate(value~Observations, head, 1, data=dat)}
f2 <- function(){dat[!duplicated(dat$Observations), ]}  
f3 <- function(){DT <- data.table(dat, key='Observations')
                 DT[J(unique(Observations)), mult="first"]}
f4 <- function(){group_by(dat, Observations) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)}

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), unit="relative")
#Unit: relative
#expr         min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#f1() 149.0736206 145.881588 143.122352 138.611025 108.063314   100
#f2()   1.8248371   1.805648   1.783553   1.736195   1.554765   100
#f3()   0.9861738   1.259007   1.279011   1.270937  11.535428   100
#f4()   1.0000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   100
```

Update with another `data.table`-approach after comment by @Arun:

```
set.seed(49)
dat <- data.frame(Observations=sample(LETTERS, 1e5, replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(1e5))
library(microbenchmark)
f1 <- function(){aggregate(value~Observations, head, 1, data=dat)}
f2 <- function(){dat[!duplicated(dat$Observations), ]}  
f3 <- function(){DT <- data.table(dat, key='Observations')
                 DT[J(unique(Observations)), mult="first"]}
f4 <- function(){group_by(dat, Observations) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)}
f5 <- function() {dt = as.data.table(dat); unique(dt, by="Observations")}

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5(), unit="relative")
#Unit: relative
#expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#f1() 274.036916 247.499012 234.616587 227.094582 8.54993826   100
#f2()   3.065027   3.059164   2.881088   2.797630 0.10404962   100
#f3()   2.122190   2.197721   2.105737   2.056280 0.08284540   100
#f4()   1.731631   1.703298   1.616957   1.584485 0.07353602   100
#f5()   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000 1.00000000   100
```

Comment: @Arun, good suggestion! See my update. Does `unique` select the first observation by default?

Comment: That's nice to know, @Arun. Might be useful in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using R base functions

```
> aggregate(Value~Observations, head, 1, data=df)  # df is your data.frame
  Observations Value
1         obs1     1
2         obs2     5
3         obs3     8
```

This one will give you the same output

```
> aggregate(Value~Observations, function(x) x[1], data=df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 library(data.table) 
 setDT(dat)[, .SD[1], by=Observations]
 #  Observations Value
 #1:        obs 1     1
 #2:        obs 2     5
 #3:        obs 3     8
```

Or for a faster way:

```
DT <- data.table(dat, key='Observations')
DT[J(unique(Observations)), mult="first"]
#   Observations Value
#1:        obs 1     1
#2:        obs 2     5
#3:        obs 3     8
```

#### Benchmarks

Not in a very big dataset

```
set.seed(49)
dat <- data.frame(Observations=sample(LETTERS, 1e6, replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(1e6))

library(microbenchmark)
f1 <- function() {aggregate(value~Observations, head, 1, data=dat)}
f2 <- function(){ dat[!duplicated(dat$Observations), ]}  
f3 <- function(){DT <- data.table(dat, key='Observations')
            DT[J(unique(Observations)), mult="first"]}

 microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit="relative")
#    Unit: relative
# expr        min         lq    median        uq       max neval
# f1() 351.098220 365.803821 356.66198 302.875946 102.496097   100
# f2()   2.299184   2.218348   2.35962   1.995709   1.701758   100
# f3()   1.000000   1.000000   1.00000   1.000000   1.000000   100
```

#### Update

Or as suggested by @Arun

```
 unique(DT, by="Observations")
```